# Sum of dateTime values whose are in String format SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Time variable returning from SQL query in dd:hh:mm format (day:hour:minute). Setting of this variable is:

```
...
   Time = cast(SUM(b.Time) / 1440 as varchar)
                + ':' +
                RIGHT('0' + cast(SUM(b.Time)/ 60 % 24 as varchar),2)
                + ':' +
                RIGHT('0' + cast(SUM(b.Time) % 60 as varchar),2),
...
```

So Every Data has its own Time and I can show it in ssrs under Time column by just saying [Time]. My problem is that I would like to add the times of each data and show a TotalTime value. An example:

```
A ---- 00:02:20
B ---- 01:00:08
Total ---- 01:02:28
```

However, Sum[Time] does not work here because Time values are string. How can I make the sum progress in this case, I couldnt find a way to do it. I appreciate if someone helps!

THanks

Comment: You can do that from SSRS. Don't cast the b.Time field to varchar and use SSRS format and Sum functions to calculate and show the data. What data type is b.Time column?

Comment: It is integer and holds a value matching the total minutes. For example if Time = 600, it is 600 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can write a formula to add the time. First convert your time (hh:mm:ss) to seconds then add the all the seconds and then again convert the total time in (hh:mm:ss) format.

Comment: that's what I couldnt do. Dont know where and how to do it.

Comment: You can go to expressions by right click on report cell. http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/lesson-8-ssrs-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression in SSRS to show formated `dd:HH:mm` minutes:

```
=FORMAT(FLOOR(Fields!Time.Value/1440),"00") & ":" &
FORMAT(FLOOR(Fields!Time.Value / 60 Mod 24),"00") & ":" &
FORMAT(FLOOR(Fields!Time.Value Mod 60),"00")
```

To get the total use this expression:

```
=FORMAT(FLOOR(Sum(Fields!Time.Value)/1440),"00") & ":" &
FORMAT(FLOOR(Sum(Fields!Time.Value) / 60 Mod 24),"00") & ":" &
FORMAT(FLOOR(Sum(Fields!Time.Value) Mod 60),"00")
```

Using this data arrangment in a tablix:

[image]

You will get this:

[image]

This works supposing you have a field of int data type that contains minutes.

Let me know if this helps.